# MySQL will or will not return duplicate rows, depending on whether a particular column is present or not. Why?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.9.8.RELEASE
Using a repository that extends CRUD
MySQL table imports CSV file.

The issue that I encountered originally, was that for some reason values under the column "Name" were repeated and also many of the values were missing, when fetching from the database.

I realized after extensive testing that values under "Name" were being duplicated (meaning multiple values would have the same name) but they were also replacing other "Name" values in the database (the ones that were missing).

I got rid of the "Intervals" column and it fixed the problem, meaning all the values were returned, not one missing, and without duplicates. What I think happens is that somehow MySQL goes by what's in the "Intervals" column, as some intervals are duplicates (eg. 10:00-10:30 could be present multiple times, but relating to different Name values)

My question is why did this happen? Is it because of the format the "Intervals" column had? (it's varchar(255) but it's written as "00:00-00:00"

```
@Controller
public class Patterns {

        @Autowired
        private PatternRepository repo;


        @RequestMapping("")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }

        @RequestMapping("searchAll")
        public ModelAndView patterns() {

            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("showinfo");


             ArrayList<Pattern> pattern =   (ArrayList<Pattern>) repo.findAll(); 



            mv.addObject("pattern", pattern);


            return mv;
        }


@Entity
public class Pattern {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    public String Intervals;

    public String Name;

    public String Code;

    public String Duration;

    public Long Id;



<h1>show info</h1>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>All Agent Activity</legend>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <th>Intervals</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${pattern}" var = "i" >

                    <tr>
                        <td>${ i.intervals }</td>
                        <td>${ i.name }</td>
                        <td>${ i.code }</td>
                        <td>${ i.duration }</td>
                    </tr>

                </c:forEach>
            </table>
    </fieldset>
```

[MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdb6p.png)

Comment: all the columns in the table are VARCHAR(255) except for Id (int, auto-increment)

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing data as text not a image we also need to know the expected result..  Also we need to know the generated query.. 
Also a table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` would be usefull.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, having read the information provided by your link, it makes a lot of sense even if the question does not require a lot of detail.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
  @Entity
  public class Pattern {


      @Id
      @GeneratedValue

      public String Intervals;

      public String Name;
```

That means the primary key is "Intervals", not name. Hence, there is no particular restriction on the "Name" attribute (at least in the java code), so there could be duplicates.

If you want "Name " to be the primary key, move `@Id` on the line right before the declaration of `Name`.
But you got an attribute called `Id`, and you probably what this to be the primary key. To make things easier,you also probably want this attribute to be autogenerated, move both `@Id`and `@GeneratedValue`right before the declaration of `Id`

Example:

```
  @Entity
  public class Pattern {

      public String intervals;

      public String name;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      public Long id;
```

PS: Please, use java naming convention: attributes in camel case: first character in lower case (`name`, not `Name`)

Comment: That solved it, thanks a lot. And thanks for the feedback, I'll be sure to improve in that aspect.